# Why is $e^{x^2+\ln(x)} = e^{x^2}\cdot x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The first step of the solution to a math problem tells me to rewrite the expression $e^{x^2+\ln(x)}$ as $e^{x^2}x$ as if the two were obviously equivalent.

Why does the logarithmic term in the exponent disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that for positive real $a$ you have $a^{b+c} = a^b\cdot a^c$

Recall that $\ln$ is the function inverse of $\text{exp}$, so you have $e^{\ln(x)}=x=\ln(e^x)$

So, $e^{x^2+\ln(x)}$ by the first expands as $e^{x^2}\cdot e^{\ln(x)}$ and then by the second as $e^{x^2}\cdot x$

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{x^2 + \ln(x)} = e^{x^2}e^{\ln(x)} = e^{x^2} x $$

The logarithmic term disappears because $e^{\ln(x)} = x$.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the two properties
$$X^{a+b}=X^aX^b\text{ and } e^{\ln(x)}=x$$
So
$$e^{x^2+\ln(x)}$$
$$=\left(e^{x^2}\right)\left(e^{\ln(x)}\right)$$
$$=\left(e^{x^2}\right)\left(x\right)$$